# Could Privacy Description messages (NSCameraUsageDescription) be taken from Cocoa Touch framework?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have created a framework that provides camera functionality. The framework will be used by multiple apps to use the camera functionality. I have created a InfoPlist.strings file and added a key and value for NSCameraUsageDescription.

Is there a way for an app using the framework to show this custom NSCameraUsageDescription privacy message from InfoPlist.strings in my framework?

Comment: Probably but isn't it up the app to describe to the user how they are using the camera?

Comment: Since the camera as a feature is owned by the framework. We have more context of what string should be used in NSCameraUsageDescription.

Comment: Probably your best bet is to add this to the instructions for developers integrating your framework as to what the appropriate string is to add to their info.plist.